# Is is possible to get information from Microsoft Identity Manager in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I am using Microsoft Graph API to get users from Azure AD, but there is low information from users...
Almost every field comes in Null, and my boss asked me if it was possible to get more information from the Microsoft identity manager (MIM). There are fields there that i don´t get with azure AD.
I am building a c# asp.net core web application , is anyway to do it?

Part of my code to get users from azure :

```
var user = await graphClient.Users
                .Request()
               
                .GetAsync();

 while (user.NextPageRequest != null)
            {
                user = await user.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What fields do you want to get from Microsoft Graph API or Microsoft identity manager (MIM)?

Comment: Fields like username, in my company is a basic first name . last name, but the thing is that not all users in the azure ad have last name, and there is no username... There is only principle name and Email, wich it doesn´t serve its point in what im doing... :/

Comment: Well i made a question to someone who works with MIM, and somehow he told me the documentation on this matter is really low, and he was able to make something like this because he had experience with the tool.. I will keep it like this for now :/

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is NO.  You cannot query MIM directly with C#.  If you understanding MIM\AADC at all you'll find use of this tool for querying the CONNECTOR SPACE - https://github.com/FIMTooler/csreporter.

There is no **supported** way of querying the Metaverse of MIM except through the Synchronization console.  You may be able to find blogs\examples of doing SQL queries against the MIM database.  Searching for "reflector" management agents might provide some examples of creating views based off the MIM DB to get Metaverse data.  IMO (with 10+ years MIM experience) separate DB with views into the MIM DB would be the simplest and best approach.

The long answer is YES, but not worth the effort.  You'd have to figure out the interface API calls for the Synchronization service.  It's not written in .NET, but the console that queries it is.  None of it is documented publicly, but if you use ILSpy or similar tool, you can try decompiling the console DLLs to figure out the interface they use to query the service.

Of course, terms and conditions would say you're not permitted to decompile the code.

Comment: When you post answers with links to resources with which you have an affiliation, [you are expected](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) to disclose that affiliation in the post. Please [edit] your answer to include your affiliation. Otherwise your post may be deleted. Please see [How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).